# Android Studio dont work with Git on Windows

Tags: android, git, ssh

I'm trying to use `SSH` key to access BitBucket repo. I generate `RSA` keys, configure host, add pub key to the BitBucket account and then successfully test it via `Git Bash`. 
When I was trying to clone my rep through the `Android Studio` I've always got an error like `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`. Then I cloned my rep through `CMD` successfully, opened it via `Android Studio` I've checked that `cmd` works fine in it but `Git GUI` doesn't, getting the same error.

In `Settings` **->** `Version Control` **->** `Git` **->** `SSH executable` setted to `Native`. I dont know how to solve this problem :(

Comment: There is no native ssh or git on Windows. Microsoft added ssh to powershell but I'm not sure on wich version of windows you are

Comment: Windows 10. Lol, solved my problem. I didn't understand right native and Built-in params for ssh. With Build-in works perfect :)

Comment: Added as answer. Glad you resolved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native `ssh` or `git` on Windows.

The solution is to use **built in** tools.